# Lambda expression with department name with branch name

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

```
<Employee>
    <Data>
        <Details type = "Personal">
            <Detail  Name ="John"   Associate Job="Job">
                <Department Name="Law" >
                    <Branch>New York</Branch>
                    <Branch>Florida</Branch>
                </Department>
                <Department Name="Lecture" >
                    <Branch>London</Branch>
                    <Branch>Brit</Branch>
                </Department>
            </Detail>
        </Details>
    </Data>
</Employee>
```

Output

```
Law --     New York,
           Florida

Lecture -- London,
           Brit
```

Lambda expression for above XML format :---

var employee = (from r in document.Descendants("Detail").Where(r => (string)r.Attribute("Name") == "John")select new { key = r.Element("Department").Attribute("Name").Value, value = (from type in (r.Element("Department").Elements("Branch")) select type.Value).ToArray() })
                                    .ToDictionary(t => t.key, t => t.value);

Only one records is coming

```
Law --     New York,
           Florida
```

Missing : -

```
Lecture -- London,
           Brit
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the Department elements first:

```
var employee = (from r in document.Descendants("Detail").Where(r => (string)r.Attribute("Name") == "John").SelectMany(x => x.Elements("Department"))
                            select new { key = r.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                value = (from type in r.Elements("Branch") select type.Value).ToArray() })
                            .ToDictionary(t => t.key, t => t.value);
```